How to use sqrt in gmp without loosing data?
I am working with big integer.
I have two equations:

$n = m^4 =  "66288484664777839292466735359294353535658376759494957"
x   =  4m - 11

To solve it I am using gmp_sqrt (two times)
   $m = gmp_sqrt(gmp_sqrt($n));

After that I am putting value of $m in equation 2. But it is not giving me the desired result because gmp_sqrt is ignoring decimal part.  How could I get desired value working in GMP environment?

Maybe gmp_sqrtrem ?

How about bcsqrt()? See: https://3v4l.org/a0o40

gmp_sqrtrem is a good choice

PHP's GMP does not implement the floating-point (mpf) functions.
If you have access to BCMath, its bcsqrt function has a scale parameter that might work for your purposes.
